# Arduino + WiFi ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Can anyone help me with communication between Arduino Uno and ESP8266-05?

I've this simple code only for testing response:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(12, 13);

void setup () {
    esp8266.begin(19200);
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop () {
    char buffer[50];
    esp8266.write("AT\r\n");
    esp8266.readBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    Serial.println(buffer);
    delay(1000);
}
```

But the response is some junk (in Serial monitor on my PC):

`1_Q¨ (X1JXþUÉÁEóAñ¡5%¥4¡1!!1%%¡5%¡4¡1¡!!G-]5`

This behaviour is the same if I'm using a simple resistor voltage divider or level shifter (http://www.banggood.com/5-Pcs-3_3V-5V-TTL-Bi-directional-Logic-Level-Converter-For-Arduino-p-951182.html).

```
Connection:
Arduino - esp
pin 12 - pin Tx
pin 13 - resistor divider 10k/20k - pin Rx

OR
Arduino - (HV) level shifter (LV) - esp
pin 12 - TxO - TxI - pin Tx
pin 13 - RxI - RxO - pin Rx

ESP reset pin - not connected
```

I don't know what's wrong, because when I turn on the Arduino and ESP module, I see on my notebook a new wifi network called AI-THINKER_012568 and I can connect to this network.

I supposed, when I turn on the ESP module, I should get a 'ready' response, but I get only some junk data. So, for the 'AT' command, I should get an 'OK' response...

I searched a lot for troubles with character set (ASCII vs UTF), but without any results.

I've tried a lot of combinations with reading (`read()`) and writing (`write()`, `print()`, `println()`) data from one serial port to another, but only with some junk response or without any response... I've tried various baud rates too.

Bonus question: when I searched for some manuals, I've only found manuals with ESP8266-01, so, is ESP8266-05 worse than the first version or is there something wrong?

Edit:

When I've simple code for arduino, which only sends data from one serial port to the second port:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 13); // RX, TX

void setup () {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {}
    Serial.println("€");

    mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop () {
    mySerial.listen();
    int i = 0;
    while (mySerial.available()) {
        char c = mySerial.read();
        Serial.write(c);
        i++;
    }
    if (i > 0) {
        Serial.println();
    }        


    int j = 0;
    while (Serial.available()) {
        char c = Serial.read();
        mySerial.write(c);
        Serial.print(c);
        j++;
    }
    if (j > 0) {
        Serial.println();
        mySerial.println();
    }
}
```

And when I upload code and turn on ESP microchip, I got something like this:

```
â-¬

ÿ
q·$aã
Å% ð´
D9$kvKþµ¿`ÈÛ¯h:¤ó[Y \B¡H$èðÍÝ×¸Jø
å
ü+¡
ð
```

First line is for '€' character, only for test. Next lines are initial response from ESP microchip. As I read in ESP documentation, when ESP microchip starts, I should got some data about version and `ready` word. Means these lines, that ESP microchip is death or only there is something wrong with reading this response?

Then when I sent 'AT' command, I got no response :(

Comment: Did you try other baud rates on software serial?

Comment: Same problem here. I can confirm this also for ESP8266-01.

Comment: **To gre_gor:** yes, I tried all baud rates, which are defined in Serial monitor drop down. I tried these baud rates for connection Arduino <-> ESP.

Comment: Did you tried to reflash the esp?

Comment: You wrote `all baud rates` but some esp's have a weird baud rate which is non-standart. It is somewhere close to 74880 or 74560 did you also try that?

Comment: [SparkFun says you need another library that they wrote for AT](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-wifi-shield-hookup-guide/using-the-esp8266-at-library) `#include <SparkFunESP8266WiFi.h> // Include the ESP8266 AT library`

Comment: **To Fruchtzwerg:** As I know, ESP-05 can't be reflashed...
**To Mert Gusloy:** I tried your baud rates, but without any response...
**To ti7:** I read this library - this is only something for better api for ESP microchip, but there is problem with communication with ESP microchip

Answer (score 0):

This is a sign of a fried board. If the board ***ever*** received 5 V or was running from the 3.3 V pin on the arduino for an extended period of time, chances are, the board is dead.

From a programming point of view, I have seen `String line = mySerial.readStringUntil("\n");` work quite well. You can then use and if statement to check if the line is `OK` or `ERROR`. If this implementation is still returning garbage at ***a baud rate of 9600***, then the board is dead.

Software serial doesn't work at a baud rate of 115200, so don't even try it. Make sure the baud rate of the board is changed to 9600 (something I see you already did) and keep it there! That isn't the issue.

These boards are very sensitive as to their power input. Giving 5 V or too little current at 3.3 V will destroy them. Trust me, I've ruined 4 of them by simply connecting them to the 3.3 V power pin on the arduino without realizing what was happening.

The code I gave you should work; I've used it in a project flawlessly...

Hope this helps :)